# what will be equivalent code for (this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea').value += '\n';) in aura?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, aura-attribute

I have written this in aura as

```
                             var newline ='';
                             newline +='\n';
                            component.set("v.input",newline);
```

but it is not working.

Comment: This is not enough detail to identify the problem. Please [edit] your post to provide a reproducible example and specific description of what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The most literal interpretation in Aura would be:

```
const myInput = component.find("myInput");
let value = myInput.get("v.value");
value += "\n";
myInput.set("v.value", value);
```

Where `myInput` is defined on the component as its `aura:id`:

```
<lightning-textarea aura:id="myInput" ...
```

Feel free to change this as you desire.